# Angular2 add dynamic routes?

Tags: angular, url, dynamic, routes, angular10

I need to add a dynamic path  before any URL
like this
if the URL was like this
HTTP://test.com/test1
I need to add 'en' to the path like this
HTTP://test.com/en/test
and I need to add this part to all main routes and submodule routes
how can I do this??

Answer (score 0):

in your btn or anchor tag:

```
routerLink="/en/{{dynamic-link}}"
```

in your app-routing.module:

```
{path: 'en/:dynamic', component: YourComponent},
```

Comment: thank you but I want to do it globally for all routes

Comment: then all you have to do is adding `path: 'en/:dynamic'` to all your routes